# В html разметке страницы появились непонятные символы, которые не видит редактор

Tags: html

В html разметке страницы появились непонятные символы, которые не видит редактор. Не понятно как их удалить они добавляют пробелы в разметке страницы. Символы видны по F12 в браузере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой редактор используете? Notepad++ попробуйте, если под виндой.

Comment: Нодпадом пользуюсь.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйтесь Notepad ++ с кодировкой UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: я так и делаю..

Comment: кодировка "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" проблема не решила. Файл изначально был UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" помогло , слишком тяжело найти файл  который пропустил.